# MeteorJS get MongoDB ID in click event

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following mongo collection in my MeteorJS app:

```
//Server side, load all the images
Images = new Mongo.Collection('images');
Meteor.startup(() => {
  if(Images.find().count() == 0){
    for(var i = 1; i < 23; i++){
      Images.insert({
        src:"img_"+i+".jpg",
        alt:"image "+i
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I pass that to a template and that works. However, I then want to retrieve the MongoDB `id` of an image (id that is the primary key/unique ID in MongoDB). I do it with the following code:

```
//Client side, get the collection and load it to the template
Images =  new Mongo.Collection('images');

Template.images.helpers({images:Images.find()});

Template.images.events({
  'click .js-del-image': (event) => {
    var imageId = event._id;
    console.log(imageId);
  }
});
```

This gives me `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? I thought `this._id` should give me the MongoDB ID.

For the record, This is my template, the `_id` attribute gets filled out:

```
<template name="images">
        <div class="row">
      {{#each images}}
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" id="{{_id}}">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="js-image img-responsive thumbnail-img" src="{{src}}"
            alt="{{alt}}" />

            <div class="caption">
                <p>{{alt}}</p>
               <button class="js-del-image btn btn-warning">delete</button>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div> <!-- / col -->
      {{/each}}
    </div> <!-- / row -->
</template>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with MeteorJs. Anyway, give id to your button and then your evebt might have have an attribute event.target.id or $(event.currentTarget).prop ('id')

Comment: Hey, I think you misunderstood. I don't want the button id attribute. I want the id of the image that I'm getting from my mongoDB, since that's what I'm iterating over (I want to delete it from the DB based on the id). I'll edit the question so that it's more clear.

Comment: I understood. Put image id to yout button id. Id="{_id}". I think you should do the meteorjs tutorials first to understand.

Comment: @pydoge Much wow. Since you got the answer, you may want to answer your own question instead of having it in the question.

Comment: @iiro This had nothing to do with meteorjs tutorials; this had to do with the fact that I didn't know the syntax sugar of JS.

Comment: @blueren Good idea, will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the declaration of a function:

- `(event) => { ... }` seems to have `_id` of `undefined`.
- `function(event) {...}` seems to have the correct context.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) for further information about `(event) => {...}` vs `function(){...}` declarations.